# Docker Mount Configuration Container Creation Error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mount, docker-container

I'm trying to create a container from a docker image for a project I'm working on (project sidewalk).  The container spins up correctly except for the last step where it gives me this error:

```
Creating projectsidewalk-db ... error                                                                                   
ERROR: for projectsidewalk-db  Cannot create container for service db: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\johns\OneDrive\documents\GitHub\sidewalkwebpage\db\init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh:rw': 
invalid mount config for type "bind": source path must be a directory

ERROR: for db  Cannot create container for service db: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\johns\OneDrive\documents\GitHub\sidewalkwebpage\db\init.sh:/docker-entrypoint initdb.d/init.sh:rw': 
invalid mount config for type "bind": source path must be a directory
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
make: *** [docker-up-db] Error 1
```

I've looked on other Stack Overflow threads and I've tried the fix where I create a new variable `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS` and set it equal to one, but it didn't work.  I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this problem.

Comment: Share your docker compose file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mount files on Windows, only directories are permitted. There was an issue for this in `moby` which was closed unresolved, because this is actually a limitation of Windows, not Docker: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30555#issuecomment-279170073.

Wrapping up:
I guess you have something like this in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
- .\db\init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh:rw
```

it should be this instead:

```
volumes:
- .\db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:rw
```

Comment: How do I change my mount?

Comment: Change `C:\Users\johns\OneDrive\documents\GitHub\sidewalkwebpage\db\init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh:rw` to what I suggested above (or link the whole `docker-compose.yaml` please if you need further help with that)

Comment: What do I use to change the path you mentioned? I can't find it.  How would I link the yml file?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure until you provide `docker-compose.yml` (please copy-paste it into your original question be editing it) but I updated my answer to be a bit more specific.

Comment: Ok, that fix worked.  However, it is giving me another error:`gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list &&   apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823 &&   apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 2
make: *** [docker-run] Error 1`

Comment: I'm not really sure which one of these command failed. I guess it's `apt-key adv`, but could you please split this command into three separate commands? Open `web`'s `Dockerfile` and you should find a line like `RUN /bin/sh -c echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /"...`. Split it at every `&&` please to new lines prepending `RUN ` before each command. You should get something like `RUN /bin/sh -c echo...`, on next line `RUN apt-key adv...`, on next line `RUN apt-get update`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205392/discussion-between-h3yduck-and-matthew-johnson).